# Center icon inside div with label css

Tags: html, css

I have this span within div

```html
<div>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined" (click)="call()">
           phone
         </span>
  <span> Phone</span>
</div>
```

the phone icon is not center align with the text phone

I tried `text-align :center` also but is is not working, this div has some outer div also if I give margin-top to icon it shifting whole row

Comment: Can you try using css flex with align-items and justify-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex to align these two spans:

```
<div style="display:flex; align-items:center">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined" (click)="call()">
    phone
  </span>
  <span> Phone</span>
</div>
```

You can write the style separately instead of inline CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` property to align this. This property sets how a flex item will grow or shrink to fit the space available in its flex container. **Note:** If the element is not a flexible item, the flex property has no effect.